# is there an option for testing java applications from the outside like we do with the web applications?

Tags: java, automation, junit

I would like some suggestions if your project has some java application elements as well as web then is there an option for testing java applications from the outside like we do with the web applications

Comment: do you mean testing a Swing applications GUI?

Comment: Are you talking about GUI applications ?

Comment: I mean Application having java application elements as well as a web application that can be tested via UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean testing desktop applications through the GUI? If so, there are many tools for doing this, both commercial and open source. Some open-source projects to google for:

- [Window Licker](http://windowlicker.googlecode.com) (I am an author of this one)
- FEST
- Marathon
- Abbot

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear to me. But from what I understand, I feel jMeter could be something that might help.

jMeter can not only test web applications (from outside) but ALSO standalone java applications.

Also, do not dismiss jMeter as a performance testing tool. There are ample features in it that makes it a good enough tool for Functional testing as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is called Blackbox testing.

Typically you would write another program that provides inputs to your applications and verifies the output. This is easier for a command line application but for GUI testing you would need to use a framework like others have mentioned.

Another approach is to write a drive that includes the jar files and directly call the public functions and do input/output testing.

Comment: Just found a tool named Jameleon (automation frameowrk havng plug ins for all types of applications). ANy comments on it